# Login to mysql programmatically

Tags: mysql, c, security

I'm writing a c program and need to login to a mysql database. I'm trying to find a simple yet secure way of storing the username and password in the program.  The program will make https calls to the mysql server.  I just need to be able to include the user/password data and I don't want to store it as a string in the program.

Anyone know a simple yet secure way to do this?

This is on a linux system.  raspberry pi debian (jessie).

Comment: So you're not using the MySQL C API, but instead make web-requests to some web-server where the database is?

Comment: What if the login and password are supplied as program's arguments (in `argv[]`)?

Comment: The question title doesn't match the actual question, you should find a better one. This is about storing credentials securely. The typical approach is to have them in a config file with restricted access.

Comment: I would prefer to use a config file than add them as program arguments.  They will be in the history.

Answer (score 0):

You should not hardcode username/password into your binary, since it is very unflexible and you will tend to *not* change this password regularly if you have to recompile the binary each time. Furthermore, binaries are usually not specially read protected, so other users might get your password.

Passing the credentials as program arguments is a bad idea, too, since it might show up in a process list, may be safed in command line histories, may be logged by auditing tools etc. pp., so your password might end up in several places you don't want it to show up.

Your best option is to employ a configuration file with the credentials and give it the minimal rights it needs, so your credentials are safe. A simple library for linux is for example [libini](https://github.com/pcercuei/libini/), which allows you to store key/value pairs in sections, but there are many other options.

Another quite safe option, which is for example employed by apache for private key passphrases and similar, is to specify a program (usually a shell script), which is executed and outputs the credentials on stdout, which is then parsed by your program. Again, you have to make sure here, that only authorized users/processes may read or execute that script.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Yes, agreed.  I've decided to use a config file and encrypt the credentials in the file.  I was hoping there was some standard, simple, easy to use techniques in standard c that would handle this sort of thing.  There really isn't.  But I've found some fairly simple encryption tools based on openssl to use to help me.